# How do I access encrypted folders from the terminal?

Tags: command-line, encryption

I encrypted the whole hard disk (via encfs) on installation of 14.04, and I want to install an HP driver only installable from the terminal. But "cd" does not recognize any encrypted file directories, e.g., desktop or downloads. "ls" does show them, but in a different color. I've tried using "sudo", but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

If you mount the encrypted disk correctly, it should be accessed just like a regular disk. If you do not mount the encrypted disk (or do so incorrectly), it will function as designed, and prevent access. To see what is mounted, just type `mount`.

Comment: Tried it, but this is what I got:

Comment: "this"? How is that supposed to convey information?

Comment: Sorry--tried to copy from terminal--didn't work. Tried to delete comment, and apparently that didn't work either. Apologies.

Comment: Sorry--tried to copy from terminal, but it didn't work. Tried to delete comment, but it didn't work either. Apologies.

Comment: You can click on "edit" and add the results to the bottom of your question - this way, some other person can get all the data by reading the question, and not have to read all the comments to see what's up.